# Make image float with text wrapping around the image?

Tags: html, css

How do you make an image with text wrapping around it when both the image and text are **in separate divs**?

I've recreated the scenario below:

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/full/yatsr/

The first part is the one I've having problem with styling it, and the second part is what I wanted to achieve.

I can't tweak the HTML since it is actually an extract from a responsive layout that it needs to have the divs set up like this.... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got something that could work!

It uses a pseudo element.

```
.yourDivWithALotOfText:before {
    content:"";
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    float:left;
}
```

Make sure all your elements are set to:

```
display: inline;
position: absolute;
```

Caveat: `padding-left` and `padding-bottom` should be set manually.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thauwa/utYkZ/

Answer (score 1):

Use image inside your div or paragraph and assign image to align left/right with horizontal and vertical space.

**Some Sample code:**

```
  <img src="http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/32854-image/First-samples-from-Sonys-new-13MP-stacked-camera-sensor-capable-of-HDR-video-show-up.jpg" border="0" align="left" hspace="10" />
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4G3Vc/)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, the issue is I cant move the current image and caption out of its parent divs like you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Your Modified Code is here: [ImageDivInsideTextFlow](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/FVuzk/1/)

html

---

```
 <h1>My current setup</h1>

<div class="template-g">
  <div>

  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Unique Rooftop Bar, Bali</h4>
    <p>
      <figure><div class="fakeImage"></div>
      <figcaption>Photo: Unique Rooftop Bar</figcaption>
    </figure>Finding the perfect sundowner bar has become a Balinese holiday ritual. For the setting alone – 360 degree views of Uluwatu Hills and sunset over the Indian Ocean – the newly opened two-storey Unique Rooftop Bar makes for a serious contender. By day, it’s a pool club, with a raised infinity-edged 25-metre pool facing the sunset. In the evening, it turns into a cocktail bar and restaurant serving an Asian-inspired menu. The earthy interior design concept is an extension of its lush green surroundings, with features such as exposed timber trusses, recycled shipwood walls, andesite stone flooring and mother-of-pearl ceiling. Unique is of course part of the new RIMBA Jimbaran Bali resort, which opened last year in the forest grounds of the well-acclaimed cliff-top Ayana Resort and Spa. www.rimbajimbaran.com</p>

     <p>Finding the perfect sundowner bar has become a Balinese holiday ritual. For the setting alone – 360 degree views of Uluwatu Hills and sunset over the Indian Ocean – the newly opened two-storey Unique Rooftop Bar makes for a serious contender. By day, it’s a pool club, with a raised infinity-edged 25-metre pool facing the sunset. In the evening, it turns into a cocktail bar and restaurant serving an Asian-inspired menu. The earthy interior design concept is an extension of its lush green surroundings, with features such as exposed timber trusses, recycled shipwood walls, andesite stone flooring and mother-of-pearl ceiling. Unique is of course part of the new RIMBA Jimbaran Bali resort, which opened last year in the forest grounds of the well-acclaimed cliff-top Ayana Resort and Spa. www.rimbajimbaran.com</p>     <p>Finding the perfect sundowner bar has become a Balinese holiday ritual. For the setting alone – 360 degree views of Uluwatu Hills and sunset over the Indian Ocean – the newly opened two-storey Unique Rooftop Bar makes for a serious contender. By day, it’s a pool club, with a raised infinity-edged 25-metre pool facing the sunset. In the evening, it turns into a cocktail bar and restaurant serving an Asian-inspired menu. The earthy interior design concept is an extension of its lush green surroundings, with features such as exposed timber trusses, recycled shipwood walls, andesite stone flooring and mother-of-pearl ceiling. Unique is of course part of the new RIMBA Jimbaran Bali resort, which opened last year in the forest grounds of the well-acclaimed cliff-top Ayana Resort and Spa. www.rimbajimbaran.com</p>
    <p class="articleHighlight">Drink in the view</p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />
<h1>What I want to achieve</h1>

<div class="template-h">

  <div>

    <figure><div class="fakeImage"></div>
      <figcaption>Photo: Unique Rooftop Bar</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <h4>Unique Rooftop Bar, Bali</h4>
    <p>Finding the perfect sundowner bar has become a Balinese holiday ritual. For the setting alone – 360 degree views of Uluwatu Hills and sunset over the Indian Ocean – the newly opened two-storey Unique Rooftop Bar makes for a serious contender. By day, it’s a pool club, with a raised infinity-edged 25-metre pool facing the sunset. In the evening, it turns into a cocktail bar and restaurant serving an Asian-inspired menu. The earthy interior design concept is an extension of its lush green surroundings, with features such as exposed timber trusses, recycled shipwood walls, andesite stone flooring and mother-of-pearl ceiling. Unique is of course part of the new RIMBA Jimbaran Bali resort, which opened last year in the forest grounds of the well-acclaimed cliff-top Ayana Resort and Spa. www.rimbajimbaran.com</p>

     <p>Finding the perfect sundowner bar has become a Balinese holiday ritual. For the setting alone – 360 degree views of Uluwatu Hills and sunset over the Indian Ocean – the newly opened two-storey Unique Rooftop Bar makes for a serious contender. By day, it’s a pool club, with a raised infinity-edged 25-metre pool facing the sunset. In the evening, it turns into a cocktail bar and restaurant serving an Asian-inspired menu. The earthy interior design concept is an extension of its lush green surroundings, with features such as exposed timber trusses, recycled shipwood walls, andesite stone flooring and mother-of-pearl ceiling. Unique is of course part of the new RIMBA Jimbaran Bali resort, which opened last year in the forest grounds of the well-acclaimed cliff-top Ayana Resort and Spa. www.rimbajimbaran.com</p>
         <p>Finding the perfect sundowner bar has become a Balinese holiday ritual. For the setting alone – 360 degree views of Uluwatu Hills and sunset over the Indian Ocean – the newly opened two-storey Unique Rooftop Bar makes for a serious contender. By day, it’s a pool club, with a raised infinity-edged 25-metre pool facing the sunset. In the evening, it turns into a cocktail bar and restaurant serving an Asian-inspired menu. The earthy interior design concept is an extension of its lush green surroundings, with features such as exposed timber trusses, recycled shipwood walls, andesite stone flooring and mother-of-pearl ceiling. Unique is of course part of the new RIMBA Jimbaran Bali resort, which opened last year in the forest grounds of the well-acclaimed cliff-top Ayana Resort and Spa. www.rimbajimbaran.com</p>
    <p class="articleHighlight">Drink in the view</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

---

```
  head,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

hr{
  margin:20px 0; 
}

.fakeImage{
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}


.template-g{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.template-g>div{
  float:left;
}

.template-g>div:first-child{/*width for image*/
  width:30%
}

.template-g>div:last-child{
  width:70%
}


.template-h>div{
  width:100%
}

.template-h figure{
  width:600px;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't made myself clear, actually I cannot move the image and its caption out of the current div like what you did because the layout is fix where the image much be in a div and the text must be in another...

Answer (score 0):

so your image is in a <div>. So give some id to that DIV and use this css
 `#divid
{float:left}`
Is it working ?